# Calling RESTful service from browser and handling 4xx class responses

Tags: rest, web-services, json, ajax, browser

I have a resource called `Logins`, and I invoke a `GET` via AJAX from the browser.  The current behavior is to return a 404 when the specific login cannot be found.

I'm using this to check whether a username is in use or not.  (when creating a new user, the username must be unique)

```
http://localhost/Logins/Matthew
```

The AJAX code works fine and can read the response's status code, however, the browser's (firefox) console flags it as an error (all 404s are).  This leads me to believe that it *may* not be the best idea to give non-successful type responses to browsers.

I'd rather not have the browser treat this as an exceptional case and flag it as an error in the console, mainly because it's alarming when the developer tools light up.

Should I:

1. Ignore the console, 404s are perfectly valid in this case.
2. Avoid using 4xx status code responses and return a less 'restful' response.
3. Change the resource as `Logins` doesn't make sense for the use-case.
4. Something else...

Browsers are the only consumer of this API, so I can change it anyway that best suits them.

Comment: How many of your end users are developers?  [How to handle business rules with a REST API?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/250692/64132) and [What is the best way to create REST API error response model and error codes system?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/270335/64132) seem to suggest a 404 is a good return in this case.

Comment: The intended end-user is the general public, I'm more concerned about possible unintended consequences of having 404 represent a valid response.  If the consumer was not a browser I would not be concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

404 is perfectly fine for this use case. 4xx status codes are client error codes, so browser treats them as such, and that is perfectly fine too.

Another kind of APIs (e.g. [JSON-RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification)) use different approaches, but since you're going RESTful, do not change response code just to make console output look pretty - it is not a use case, users are not supposed to inspect console output.

Comment: This was one of my thoughts on the subject, and it sounds like it's the way to go, however, I'm going to wait a bit to see if there's any opposing viewpoints.